# Showing when the Central Limit Theorem does and does not hold for symmetric random walks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to show the following for two sums of random variables:
Let ${X_n},  n∈ \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of independent random
variables.

First, assume that
$P(X_n = 1) = P(X_n = −1) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{n^2})\\$ and $P(X_n =
\sqrt{n}) = P(X_n = −\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2n^2}$

Prove that for the sums  $S_n = X_1 + · · · + X_n$ the Central Limit
Theorem is valid.

Next consider $P(X_n = 1) = P(X_n = −1) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{n})\\$ and $P(X_n =
\sqrt{n}) = P(X_n = −\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2n}$

Prove that in this case the Central Limit Theorem does not hold.

I'm not really sure how I should approach this.  Further more what is the intuition that the CLT falls apart when we remove that power of n from the denominator.

Comment: In both cases, define $Y_n=X_n/|X_n|$ then $(Y_n)$ is i.i.d. with symmetric Bernoulli distribution hence the CLT applies to $T_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$. Now, in the first case, $\sum P(X_n\ne Y_n)$ converges hence $|T_n-S_n|\leqslant R$ for every $n$, where $R$ is almost surely finite, in particular, $$-R/\sqrt{n}+T_n/\sqrt{n}\leqslant S_n/\sqrt{n}\leqslant T_n/\sqrt{n}+R/\sqrt{n}$$ and $R/\sqrt{n}\to0$ almost surely, hence the CLT also applies to $S_n$. In the second case, $\sum P(|X_n|=\sqrt{n})$ diverges hence $X_n=\pm\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often hence the CLT fails. In the end, the crucial ...

Comment: ... argument is that the series $\sum P(X_n\ne\pm1)$ converges or diverges, plus Borel-Cantelli lemma.